# iterating through an array in a controller javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, controller

I am making a request to my database and that is returning it fine but I am wanting to store it into an array so that i can iterate through it again in another request. However, I can't do it as I cannot access the array length in my code.

```
'use strict'
var myApp = angular.module('dashApp', []);

var availiable = [];

myApp.controller('dashCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    var getavailable = function() {
      $http.get('/availableList').success(function(response) {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var av = new Object();
            av.Building = response[i].BuildingName;
            av.Townhall = response[i].Townhall;
            availiable.push(av);
          }
        };

        var main = function(req, response) {
          getavailable();
          console.log(availiable);
          console.log(avInt);
          for (var i = 0; i < availiable.length; i++) {
            console.log("in forloop");
            var count = getCount(availiable[i]);

          }
          $scope.BuilingList = $scope.finalList;
          $scope.finalList = "";

        };

        main();

      }]);
```

Comment: what do you see inside response?

Comment: I get an array of Objects from my Json query, this sets to the array availiable fine but availiable.length doesnt seem to produce anything

Comment: `$http` is **asynchronous** ... you are trying to access the data before it has been received. It's like eating a pizza that hasn't been delivered yet

Comment: @charlietfl wonderful example :P

Comment: @Sajeetharan I stole that concept...can't take full credit....but it does dummy down the concept quite well. People may not initially understand asynchronicity...but they sure know how pizza delivery works

Comment: Oh right, didnt realise that. Thanks for the help both of you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to even use the **for loop**

This should work fine.

```
 $http.get('/availableList').success(function(response) {
    available = response.data;
   ....
```